# Ankhsvn - do not commit config files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

In ankhsvn  how do I prevent a certain version file (e.g.connectionStrings.config) from being committed

Comment: Rightclick + Subversion + Ignore File?! Or along those lines. Then it shows in ignored files in your pending changes and wont be committed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is a new file, use right click -> Subversion -> Ignore, and choose an appropriate option.

If it's an existing file right click -> Subversion -> Move To Change List -> ignore-on-commit. This prevents the file from being automatically selected, but you can still commit it by right-clicking or selecting it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst Sander is correct, if you're working with other developers or use a build server, then I'd recommend you create a `connectionStrings.default.config` which is version controlled. Then as part of a [BeforeBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) target in your project file, copy to `connectionStrings.config` if it doesn't exist.

That way other developers can see when the default configuration changes through the SVN log when they update working copies. If you use a build server, it can can be configured to always create a clean configuration based on the default, which is useful for setting up test environments and ensuring config changes are respected.

FWIW, what I do with CruiseControl.NET is pass a MSBuild property which identifies this as a build server build, then as part of BeforeBuild target it deletes any existing configuration files before creating new ones based on the defaults.